# Custom resize de uma div

Tags: javascript, html, css

Como personalizar o `resize` para que seja possível redimensionar em qualquer lugar da parte de baixo da `div`
Exemplo do próprio **stackoverflow**:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
.caixa {
  background-color: #444;
 /* margin: 100px auto; */
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  padding-bottom:20px;
}
.ta {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width:33%;}
.ta1 {
  background-color: #000;
}
.ta2 {
  background-color: #ddd;
}
.ta3 {
  background-color: #888;
}
textarea {
  resize:none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="caixa">
<div class="ta ta1"><textarea></textarea></div>
<div class="ta ta2"><textarea></textarea></div>
<div class="ta ta3"><textarea></textarea></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Boa noite!
Eu copiei do próprio site aqui! "Stackoverflow" testei e deu certo, mas no canto. <!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false --> <!-- language: lang-html --> <textarea id="wmd-input" class="wmd-input wz-element s-input bar0 processed" name="post-text" cols="52" rows="15" tabindex="80" data-wz-state="8" data-min-length="" style="opacity: 1; height: 43px;"></textarea> <!-- end snippet -->

Comment: Resposta curta: vai ter que usar Javascript

Comment: Com jQuery UI vc consegue isso fácil. Se quiser posso postar um exemplo.

Comment: Você poderia me passar um exemplo simples com comentarios explicando?

Comment: Pode ver aqui, com comentários: https://jsfiddle.net/kcth8j5v/11/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bem, o mais próximo que consegui fazer foi usando o evento `mousemove`.

Eu detecto se a div `.drag` foi acionada para aumentar o tamanho do `textarea` de acordo com a posição que estou movendo o mouse (pra cima ou baixo)

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
  var lastPageY = 0;
  var textarea = document.querySelector('textarea');
  var drag = document.querySelector('.drag');
  
  drag.addEventListener('mousedown', function () {
       drag.classList.add('active');
  }, true);
  
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  
      var dragEnabled = drag.classList.contains('active') && e.which === 1;
      if (! dragEnabled) return;
 
    // Movimento continua na mesma posição anterior. Então nada é feito
    
    if (e.pageY === lastPageY) return;
    
    // posição da página atual menos o tamanho do .drag
   
    var height = e.pageY - drag.offsetHeight;
    
    textarea.style.height = height + 'px';
    
    // salva a posição anterior :)
    lastPageY = e.pageY;
    
  })
  
  window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
      drag.classList.remove('active');
      console.log('stopped');
  }, false)
})
```

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box; }
.drag
{
  background-color: #ddd;

  width: 100%;
  user-select:none;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  display: flex;
  height: 15px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.drag.active{
    background-color: #049;
    cursor: move;
    color: white;
}
.container textarea{
  display: block;
  resize: none;
  width: 100%;
  user-select: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div class="drag">
   &bullet;  &bullet;  &bullet;
  </div>
</div>
```

Na parte onde é definido o `height`, eu particularmente usaria um `Math.min` e `Math.max` para definir o tamanho mínimo e máximo que o elemento poderia alcancar de altura.